# How do I bind multiple ports using AsynchronousServerSocketChannel?

Tags: java, serversocket, channel, nio2

I'm trying to create a server with an asynchronous communication model and want to bind multiple ports, but it throws an error "AlreadyBoundException" when I call one more than bind method. Is there any possible way to do this?
Here's my code

```
try(AsynchronousServerSocketChannel listener = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open()){
                if(listener.isOpen()){
                    listener.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_RCVBUF, 4*1024);
                    listener.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
                    listener.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9001));
                    listener.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9002));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind a single `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel` (or any other `NetworkChannel` or `Socket`) to one port. The [`bind()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) method throws an [AlreadyBoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AlreadyBoundException.html) if the socket is already bound

You can, however, use with multiple `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel`, one for each port.